# Android, Retrofit: Getting API data by going through multiple urls

Tags: android, retrofit

So I am trying to get json data from API, but problem is that it just contains URLs that lead to actual data. Example:

```
// e.g. base url api.someapi.com/v0/
{
  "count": 246,
  "results": [
    {
      "href": "https://api.someapi.com/v0/items/akluhdkunsduawhbd",
      "name": "item A"
    },
    {
      "href": "https://api.someapi.com/v0/items/fgluorkunfythmhbc",
      "name": "item B"
    },
    // more stuff...
  ]
}
```

When you go to the actual item it has the data I need, but some of that data is again under a different url e.g. `https://api.someapi.com/v0/items/fgluorkunfythmhbc/type/esgrtesrsuykbdv`

How do I get all that data if I want to display each item in a list with full details?

I currently have something like this:

```
Call<Collection> call = api.getCollection();
call.enqueue(new Callback<Collection>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<Collection> call, Response<Collection> response) {
        ArrayList<CollectionData> collectionDataList = response.body().getResults();
        // Can get urls of each item but how to get the data?
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<Collection> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.e(TAG, t.getMessage());
    }
});
```

Collection class:

```
public class Collection {
    @SerializedName("count")
    @Expose
    private String count;

    @SerializedName("results")
    @Expose
    private ArrayList<CollectionData> results;

    public String getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(String count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    public ArrayList<CollectionData> getResults() {
        return results;
    }

    public void setResults(ArrayList<CollectionData> results) {
        this.results = results;
    }
}
```

ApiService interface:

```
public interface ApiService {
    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    @GET("items")
    Call<Collection> getCollection();

    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    @GET("items/{id}")
    Call<Card> getItem(@Path("id") String id);
}
```

Nested calls or some other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some projects we need to fetch data from multiple urls. Nested calls is a suitable solution for this problem, Also you can add more Api service to handle dynamic url requests. Retrofit 2.0 support request url as parameter with @url annotation.

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json") 
    @GET
    Call<Card> getItem(@url string url , @Path("id") String id); }
```